# How to reuse UIWebview Just like UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview

I want to reuse `UIWebview` Just like `TableViewcell` instead of allocating again and again.

Comment: UIWebView inside tableView or what?

Comment: No Just like  how Tableview reuse one tableview cell , I want to create one reusable UIWebview

Comment: and use that reusable uiwebView where?

Comment: because , we reuse cells as they are used many times inside UITableView. so, where are using many webView instances.

Comment: In my custom created Pagecontroller type component

Comment: yes i am going to use uiwebview many times in my project view controller

Comment: in such cases , you can reuse it. For example, lets say there is a requirement to display webView in tableViewCell. Then you should subClass UITableViewCell, add a class property instance of UIWebView and add it as subView to cell. similarly, you can use it in pagecontroller

Comment: can you provide some codesnippet for the same if possible

Comment: google it. you can find answers to it in SO also. http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: you are doing something SO wrong if you need this :)